# Edit all attributes of all instances of a ForeignKey in Model Admin Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Building an app to quickly add numbers to foreign keys.

So I am quite new to Django and I already looked for related questions here and in the documentation of Django. What I found was the inline AdminModel, but that is not really, what I want.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date= models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

I would like to have a table with all instances of the ForeignKey.So for example, using the tutorial code, it should be possible to edit every choice_text and votes to all questions simultaneously (so that one not necessarily has to jump between the different questions to add content). Is this possible?
Thanks in advance for any help!

[image: Here a mock-up of the project:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are starting from the wrong point, and that's why you had trouble to explain what you wanted to achieve. You are trying to start from the `Question` model while what you want is to update `Choice`s in bulk (main issue) and display the text of the related question (secondary issue).

You can edit `Choice`s in bulk using this [`list_editable`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable):

```
class ChoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['__str__', 'question_text', 'choice_text', 'votes']
    list_editable = ['choice_text', 'votes']
    ordering = 'question'

    def question_text(self, obj):
        return obj.question.question_text
    question_text.short_description = "Question"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Django reference for the meta api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/meta/).
Have a look at the [reference for model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/).
A combination of these should solve your problem.
Pseudo code,

```
all_fields = MyModel._meta.fields
for field in all_fields:
    //Check if field is foreign key, field.get_internal_key() should work.
    //Find foreign key
```